# Creating child instances on an aggregate root in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have been reading Eric Evan's book on DDD and on page 139 he states:

"if you needed to add elements inside a preexisting AGGREGATE, you might create a FACTORY METHOD on the root of the AGGREGATE"

I would assume that could be implemented something like this where the method NewLineItem is used to create and add a new line item to the order.

```
class Order
{
   public IEnumerable<LineItem> LineItems { get; }

   public void NewLineItem(Product product, int quantity);
}
```

Another way I could think of doing this is to move the factory method into the collection itself.  Something like this below.  I could then add a new item by calling LineItems.New(...).

```
class Order
{
   public LineItems LineItems { get; }

   public class LineItems : IEnumerable<LineItem>
   {
       public void New(Product product, int quantity);
   }
}
```

What are the pros/cons to each approach?  Are there any gotchas with moving the factory method into a collection?  We are currently trying to figure out the best way to implement a large domain model.  We are concerned that some of these root aggregate models will get bloated with numerous factory methods and deletion methods such as RemoveLineItem(LineItem).  Our thinking is that moving these factory methods to their collections helps organize the design and keeps the root aggregate less cluttered with methods.  Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is always that "law" of Demeter business :)

The aggregate root (AR) is going to be responsible for the integrity and invariants.  It may be possible that you will have an invariant along the lines of "maximum order total of $50 and no more than 6 line items at any time".  The collection will not have access to any of this information (well, perhaps the count).  So the idea is that the AR handles these interactions.

If you are concerned with bloat or find yourself with ARs that are unwieldy it may indicate a problem with your design.  Vaughn Vernon covers these scenarios quite nicely in *his* book.  You really do want highly cohesive ARs and it can be tricky to identify them correctly.  A couple of iterations may be required to get the most comfortable design.

So I would try and stick with Eric's advice and handle the interactions on the AR itself as far as is practically possible.

Answer (score 3):

One advantage of having the factory method on the AR directly is that it makes the AR aware of the changes and allows it to enforce it's invariants. Not only that, but because the method is aware of the internal state of the AR you may be able to reduce the number of arguments passed to the factory method (most useful when creating other related ARs).

E.g. `registration = course.register(registrant)` vs `registration = new Registration(registrant, courseId)`

Also, `LineItem` becomes an implementation detail so the client doesn't need to be aware of that class.

The fact that you are asking this question and are actually worried of having too many methods on your ARs is perhaps an indicator that you may be clustering together objects that do not belong together.

Do not lose sight of the AR main purpose: it's a transactionnal boundary allowing to protect invariants. If there's no invariant to protect then clustering may be unecessary or even undesirable.

I would strongly advise you to read [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) by Vauhgn Vernon.

Comment: Sounds like you and Eban are both saying the same thing.  Appreciate the feedback and will look into Vernon's book.